# How do I change dropdown comments when a radiobutton is selected?

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, foreach, laravel-blade

```
<select class="form-control" id="select">
    @if(document.getElementById('radiobuttonID')=='pages')
         @foreach($page as $row)
            <option class='opt' id='{{ $row->id}}' data-id='{{ $row->id}}'>{{$row->name}}</option>
         @endforeach
    @else
         //Do the else thing
    @endif
</select>
```

This will surely not work, but I hope you see the idea (take the above as pseudo-code). Is there a way to store an ID to a variable, then put it inside a if condition?

Comment: You can't mix php and javascript like that. PHP is executed before the page loads, and javascript after it. You'll want to look into javascript/jquery for changing contents based on input change.

Comment: I already know that. but I just wanna give the idea. cause I already wasted so many hours in this function. This is the last in my task. I'm still a newbie in web dev so ...........im still weak

Comment: Improved grammar and expression.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done purely with blade, you need javascript as well, I'd suggest:

```
<select class="form-control" id="select1">

     @foreach($page as $row)
        <option class='opt' id='{{ $row->id}}' data-id='{{ $row->id}}'>{{$row->name}}</option>
     @endforeach
</select>

<select class="form-control" id="select2" style="display:none;">
    // do the else thing
</select>
```

And then with javascript(and jquery):

```
$('#radiobuttonID').change(function(event){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) 
    {
        $('#select1').show();
        $('#select2').hide();
    }else{
        $('#select2').show();
        $('#select1').hide();
    }
});
```